# What's wrong with higher dimensional nearby cycles?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, derived-categories

Suppose we have a complex algebraic variety $X$ with a map $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ with $Y=f^{-1}(0)$. Let $\overset{\sim}{\mathbb{C}}$ be the universal cover of $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ and consider the fiber product $\overset{\sim}{X}= X \times_{\mathbb{C}} \overset{\sim}{\mathbb{C}}$. Given a perverse sheaf $F$ on $X$, we may apply the nearby cycles functor $\psi$ to $F$ by first pulling back to $\overset{\sim}{X}$, pushing back to $X$, and then pulling back to $Y$.

It seems like the definition of nearby cycles doesn't rely on the fact that the base of $f$ is one-dimensional, so I assume there are some nice properties of $\psi$ that fail when our base has dimension $\geq 2$.

What are the properties of the functor $\psi$ that fail when we replace $\mathbb{C}$ with something higher dimensional, say $\mathbb{C}^r$, for $r>1$, and why?

Comment: What are you intending to subtract and take the universal cover of?

Comment: Initial problems are failure of constructibility and failure of base change. That said, there is a theory of higher dimensional nearby cycles, see https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~illusie/vanishing1b.pdf.

Comment: @WillSawin Well I guess I was thinking that we could just take $\mathbb{C}^r-\{0\}$, in which case the universal cover would be the space itself

Comment: @user125639 Where exactly does constructibility fail?

Comment: No universal cover means you're just taking the usual pushforward. This is a totally valid construction, and indeed preserves constructibility, but it just isn't nearby cycles.

Comment: @WillSawin Ah that makes sense. The natural follow-up question in my mind is what if we take as a base some space $Z$ such that $Z-\{pt\}$ has nontrivial $\pi_1$?

Comment: @leibnewtz Probably you will not get something that behaves like nearby cycles unless $Z -\{0\}$ has all higher homotopy groups vanishing, so its universal cover is contractible. This should ensure that if you have a constant sheaf, for instance, the nearby cycles will simply be the same constant sheaf and not something more complicated, which makes vanishing cycles interesting.

Comment: @liebnewtz: I was referring to the higher-dimensional nearby cycles functor in the article I linked, not the one you defined, which as Will pointed out is just the pushforward. Section 1.2 explains an example where constructibility fails.